# Insert data on two table PDO

Tags: php, pdo

please help me..whenever I submit form my data goes to two tables 'questions' ans 'answer'..The problem is that in answer table the 'answer' column is not inserted..
Here is my code...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $ques_id=mt_rand(10000,100000 );
    $question = trim($_POST['question']);
    $opt = array();
    $opt[1] = trim($_POST['opt1']);
    $opt[2] = trim($_POST['opt2']);
    $opt[3] = trim($_POST['opt3']);
    $opt[4] = trim($_POST['opt4']);
    $answer = trim($_POST['answer']);
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO question (question) VALUES (:question)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);
    if($stmt)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(":question", $question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        foreach($opt as $key => $ansName)
        {
            if($ansName != '')
            {
                if($answer == $key)
                {
                    $rquery = "INSERT INTO answer(ques_id,answer,opt) values(:ques_id, '1', :ansName)";
                }
                else
                {
                    $rquery = "INSERT INTO answer(ques_id,answer,opt) values(:ques_id, '0', :ansName)";
                }
                $result = $conn->prepare($rquery);
                $result->bindParam(":ques_id", $ques_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindParam(":ansName", $ansName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->execute();
                // Close statement
                unset($result);
            }
        }
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Question Inserted Successfully";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        unset($stmt);
    }
}
?>
```

The answer column is left blank...please help

Comment: `var_dump($ansName)` gives what? You could use ternary and get rid of conditional `$right_answer = $answer == $key ? 1 : 0;` then you just need one query and `values(:ques_id, ?, :ansName)` while binding `$right_answer`.

Comment: Maybe is because type column is different , Check type column answer and try without quotes (0 or 1) in your query for integer type

Comment: Another point `question` should have an auto incrementing column. Your id generating, `mt_rand(10000,100000 )`, can cause collisions.

Comment: @user3783243 i m sorry, but i didn't get anything what u said..as i am new to PDO and PHP

Comment: @JuanSebastiánMoreno I removed quotes and my type is integer..but still not working..please help

Comment: If your execute your query directly in your db tool, Does It work?

Comment: Can you provide the form that is used to submit the data?